# Results do not show up

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
  <!doctype html>

        <html lang="en">

        <head>

          <meta charset="utf-8">

          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

          <title>collapsible demo</title>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

          <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

          <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>



        <section id="page1" data-role="page">
            <header data-role="header">
                <h3 style="color:#3CF">Astrophoto Tool</h3>
            </header>    
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">        
                <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#rul" class="ui-btn-active">Rule 600</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#at">Advanced Tool</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#hlp">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="rul" >
                         <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                           <div data-role="content">
              <div align="center" style="color:#0F0">No Star Trails Exposure</div>
              <p align="center" style=" color:#FFFF00">Rule 600 </p>
            </div>
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#lens").on("keyup", function () {
            var lens = $(this).val();
            //var fullframe = 0;  // initialize the sum to zero
            var fullframe = 600 / lens;
            $('#fullframe').val(fullframe.toFixed(2));
            var apsccanon = 600 / (lens * 1.6);
            $('#apsccanon').val(apsccanon.toFixed(2));
            var apscnikon = 600 / (lens * 1.5);
            $('#apscnikon').val(apscnikon.toFixed(2));
            var apscolympus = 600 / (lens * 2.0);
            $('#apscolympus').val(apscolympus.toFixed(2));

            });
        });
        </script>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                <form action="">Lens: Focal  Length (mm)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='lens' style="color:#FF6"/>
                    <br>Full Frame: (Time in Seconds)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='fullframe' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly>
                    <br>APS-C (Canon): (Time in Seconds)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='apsccanon'  value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
                    <br>APS - C (Nikon/Sony/Pentax): (Time in Seconds)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='apscnikon' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
                    <br>APS - C (Olympus/Panasonic): (Time in Seconds)
                     <input type='text' id='apscolympus' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />


                    <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
                </form>
            </div>

            </div>
                    </div>                               


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pix,#lens,#dec").on("keyup", function () {
            var pix  = $(this).val();
            var lens = $(this).val();
            var dec  = $(this).val();
            var res  = (14*pix*2)/lens*cos((dec/180)*22/7);
            $('#res').val(res.toFixed(2));
            });
        });
        </script>          




                    <div id="at" >
                         <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                       <form action="">Sensor Pixel Size (examp 4.3)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='pix' style="color:#FF6"/>     
                    <br>
                        Lens: Focal  Length (mm)
                    <br>
                    <input type='text' id='lens' style="color:#FF6"/>       

                    <br>
                    Star Declination (degrees)
                    <input type='text' id='dec' style="color:#FF6"/>
                    <br> Result (secs)
                    <input type="text" id="res" value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />

                    <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">    

                    </form>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hlp" >
                         <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                            Help
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="abt" >
                        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                            <p>This application is for astrophotographers. There are 
                            two tools.<br> 1. Rule 600 (which is quite accurate) and <br>2. Advancded tool
                            which requires a few more inputs and the result gives better accuracy.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </div>
            </div>

            <footer data-role="footer">
                <h3>Footer</h3>
            </footer>
        </section>
        </body>
        </html>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 Results text box remains blank. Have I put the jquery script in the wrong place for

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: pleas put this code in a snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Simple enough to check for errors thrown, will see that `cos()` is undefined

Comment: Math.cos() is the function

Comment: Absolutely. It is Math.cos() Thanks.

Comment: wheres is `cos()` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 inputs with id="lens". Make them unique across tabs.

Instead of using $(document).ready(function() {... put all your script at the bottom of the page just before closing the BODY tag and use the jQM pagecreate event instead.

Using $(this) 3 times in the keyup handler will just give you the same value 3 times (whichever one you typed last).

In addition to using Math.cos(), you can use Math.PI instead of (22 / 7).

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {

    $("#lens").on("keyup", function () {
        var lens = $(this).val();
        //var fullframe = 0;  // initialize the sum to zero
        var fullframe = 600 / lens;
        $('#fullframe').val(fullframe.toFixed(2));
        var apsccanon = 600 / (lens * 1.6);
        $('#apsccanon').val(apsccanon.toFixed(2));
        var apscnikon = 600 / (lens * 1.5);
        $('#apscnikon').val(apscnikon.toFixed(2));
        var apscolympus = 600 / (lens * 2.0);
        $('#apscolympus').val(apscolympus.toFixed(2));
    });

    $("#pix,#lens2,#dec").on("keyup", function () {        
        var pix = $("#pix").val();
        var lens = $("#lens2").val();
        var dec = $("#dec").val();
        var res = (14 * pix * 2) / lens * Math.cos(dec * Math.PI / 180);
        $('#res').val(res.toFixed(2));
    });

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jjfn5n9r/1/)**

Comment: I've put the scripts before the <body> tag. Yes it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 elements with the same ID, you have two elements with ID of `"lens"`. Also, you need to replace that `cos()` with `Math.cos()`. Lastly, you need to separate out your keyup functions per each input. and use `parseInt()` to force int. Try this:

```
$("#pix,#lens_test,#dec").on("keyup", function () {
    var pix = parseInt($("#pix").val());
    var lens = parseInt($("#lens_test").val());
    var dec = parseInt($("#dec").val());
    var res = (14 * pix * 2) / lens * Math.cos((dec / 180) * 22 / 7);
    $('#res').val(res.toFixed(2));
});
```